# Grouping by two columns with NAs in a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse, na

Assume that I have a tibble that looks like:

```
   cell_type_A      cell_type_B        gene            score_A           score_B
     <fct>             <fct>           <chr>            <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 cd4_naive_A       cd4_naive_B       EEF1A1           0.447              0.440
 2 cd4_naive_A       cd4_naive_B       RPL5             0.405              0.466
 3 cd4_naive_A       cd4_naive_B       RPL3             0.310              0.377
 4 cd4_naive_A       cd4_naive_B       RPL4             0.425              0.264
 5 cd4_naive_A       NA                RPS5             0.335              0
 6 cd4_naive_A       NA                GNB2L1           0.329              0    
 7 NA                cd4_naive_B       TMEM66           0                  0.563
 8 NA                cd4_naive_B       BTG1             0                  1.10 
 9 cd4_helper_A      cd4_helper_B      EEF1D            0.335              0.262    
10 cd4_helper_A      NA                RPL6             0.260              0
```

I would like to calculate the correlation between scores of pairs of cell types from A and B.

Usually, this would do the job:

```
tibble %>%
   group_by(cell_type_A, cell_type_B) %>%
       summarize(cor(score_A, score_B))
```

However, I would like to include scores of lines with NAs in the calculates.

In the example above, when calculating the correlation of cd4_naive_A vs. cd4_naive_B,
this should include lines 1-8 (not 1-4)

How can I achieve this with the tidyverse syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can consider `tidy::fill` down the `NA` value with the previous one.

```
df <- data.frame( cell_type_A = c(rep('cd4_naive_A', 6), rep(NA, 2)),
            cell_type_B = c(rep('cd4_naive_B', 4),rep(NA, 2),rep('cd4_naive_B', 2)))

  cell_type_A cell_type_B
1 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
2 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
3 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
4 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
5 cd4_naive_A        <NA>
6 cd4_naive_A        <NA>
7        <NA> cd4_naive_B
8        <NA> cd4_naive_B

tidyr::fill(df, c(cell_type_A, cell_type_B), .direction = 'down')

  cell_type_A cell_type_B
1 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
2 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
3 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
4 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
5 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
6 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
7 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
8 cd4_naive_A cd4_naive_B
```